# How to rewrite from old url to new url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Any one have solution on "How to rewrite from http://domain-name.com/index.php?action=Abu-Dhabi-Airport-Free-Zone-ADAFZ to http://domain-name.com/Abu-Dhabi-Airport-Free-Zone-ADAFZ" using .htaccess file.

Comment: Simple! Just use mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with help of **mod_rewrite**, there is many online generators available, one of them gave me this solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works universally on both vhost and non-vhost configurations, and takes into account the existance of static files and/or folders.

In the php application simple use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to do whatever you want. No parameter is needed for it. Nothing else needs to be re-written, ever, as the PHP application determines what to do with an url.

```
# MAGIC: automatically determine correct rewriteRule regardless of virtualdocumentroot setting.
<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}:::%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+):::\1
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}:::%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !^(.+):::\1
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# All this is useless if mod_vhost_alias is not active
<IfModule !mod_vhost_alias.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```